# Join twice tables two keys same data in column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How-to join two tables witch two keys eg.

```
$this->db->join('ip_clients', 'ip_clients.client_id = ip_invoices.client_id'); 

$this->db->join('ip_clients', 'ip_clients.client_id = ip_invoices.recipient_id');
```

I have to place this data in the array

regards

Comment: i read it twice - but i can't understand what you want...maybe is https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html helping ?

Comment: If you have working plain MySQL query, just pass the string to `$this->db->query($string);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliases to distinct tables.

```
$this->db->join('ip_clients clientIp', 'clientIp.client_id = ip_invoices.client_id');
$this->db->join('ip_clients recipientIp', 'recipientIp.client_id = ip_invoices.recipient_id');
```

Comment: @SławomirDworaczek Please edit your post and add the full request. You have to replace ip_clients by the alias in the reste of the request (select, conditions, etc).